# ["CompileError: command 'c:\\\\mingw\\\\bin\\\\gcc.exe' failed with exit status 1\n"]

Tags: python, cython, mingw32

I tried all the options to make `mingw32` compiler work, but every time I get this error

> ```
> CompileError: command 'c:\\\\mingw\\\\bin\\\\gcc.exe' failed with exit status 1\n
> ```

and don't know how to fix it.

Steps that I have done:

1. Installed Anaconda 2.7 win 32 bits (Although my computer is 64 bits, but since the python is working I assume it should not be a problem)
2. Installed Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7
3. Installed `mingw32` and added to system environment path (I tested at command prompt by calling `gcc` and it is working)
4. Created `distutils.cfg` in `C:\Python27\Lib\distutils` folder

I appreciate if someone could help me on this.

Comment: You can probably find a more useful error message if you scroll up. `CompileError` is usually the last thing it prints, but it does give the more complete description first.